# Specs for 15,000 concurrent website users

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, nginx, httpd

Can some one tell me if this specs can support up to 15000 users online (in same time not /day):

- Dual Processor Quad Core Xeon 5570 - 2.93GHz (Nehalem) - 2 x 8MB cache w/HT
- 34 Gb ram
- 4 X 300 Gb sa-scsi 15k with raid 10
- 1000mbps connection

The software installed on the server is the vBulletin Forum serving dynamic content.

Comment: Depends on your application.

Comment: You need to provide wayyyyy more detail than just vBulletin. Do some benchmarking/estimates and come back with the results. We can't help you if you don't help us.

Answer (score 4):

It depends totally on what you're trying to do. A static website? Probably no problem at all? A website where each page requires a large amount of CPU & memory before it can output the results? You're going to have problems. Is it mainly plain text? Does it output a 1Mb graphic for each user?

The best way to know is to use benchmarking software to find out what the site's requirements are, and by extension, if it can handle the load you're expecting.

[Here](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#LOAD) is a list of different programs. Loadrunner will without doubt do it for you, but I'm sure there are others which will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are sites out there that serve 30,000 concurrent connections from a single web host, and there are sites that need hundreds of servers for the same load. You need to drill much deeper in terms of specifics and testing before you can answer this for your scenario.

Read this:
http://plentyoffish.wordpress.com/2006/06/10/microsoft-aspnet-20-performance/
It's asp specific but with the info you're currently running with, it applies equally.